# Function is always returning undefined

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

I have a problem where `getCurrentOption` is always returning undefined, and I can't for the love of coding figure out why. Because I have 2 other functions (`coForms.toggleSelect` and `coForms.isSelectToggled`) identical in functionality and they work fine.

For some reason `select.currentOption` is set correctly in `coForms.selectOption` but when I try and fetch the value in `select.getCurrentOption` it's not there anymore.. Is it losing a reference or something somewhere? I'm not too familiar with the controller as syntax nor hooking it up to a directive like this.

What is happening?

`CoFormsCtrl`:

```
var coForms = this;

coForms.toggleSelect = function(select) {
    select.isToggled = !select.isToggled;
};

coForms.isSelectToggled = function(select) {
    return select.isToggled ? true : false;
};

coForms.selectOption = function(select, option) {
    select.currentOption = option;
};

/* This is always returning undefined atm, still search for the cause */
coForms.getCurrentOption = function(select) {
    return select.currentOption;
};
```

Directive:

```
coForms.directive('coSelect', [function() {

    return {
        restrict: 'E',
        scope: {
            default: '=',
            list: '=',
            label: '@'
        },
        controller: 'CoFormsCtrl',
        controllerAs: 'co',
        templateUrl: 'app/views/components/co-forms/co-select.html',
        link: function(scope, element, attrs) {

        }
    };
}]);
```

Directive template:

```
<div class="co-select-form-control">
    <ul class="list-reset co-select">
        <li ng-click="co.toggleSelect(this)" class="co-select-option clickable">
            <span ng-bind="co.getCurrentOption(this) || default"></span>
            <ul ng-show="co.isSelectToggled(this)" class="list-reset bg-light co-select-dropdown">
                <li ng-repeat="option in list" ng-if="option !== co.getCurrentOption(this)" 
                        ng-click="co.selectOption(this, option)" ng-bind="option" class="co-select-option"></li>
            </ul>
        </li>
    </ul>
    <span class="co-select-icon">
        <i class="icon icon-keyboard-arrow-{{co.isSelectToggled(this) ? 'up' : 'down'}}"></i>
    </span>
</div>
```

Then I just use it like this:

```
<co-select list="video.config.upload.status" default="video.config.upload.status[0]"></co-select>
```

Comment: It seems `getCurrentOption()` gets call before `selectOption()`. And based on the controller.js code, you never initialize `select.currentOption` in any where. So I guess that's why you have undefined atm.

Comment: @ShaohaoLin How would I initialize it using 'this' in the controller then? Because it needs to be initialized on the select's 'this' and not the controller 'this'.

Comment: You have a directive `co-select`. Can you show us the code for that? Or provide us with a [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/)? It's hard to figure out how to connect to something we can't see.

Comment: How do you define the `co-select` directive?

Comment: I know `directive`, but in your case, did you define `coSelect`? Do you have link function, what the return type and etc?

Comment: @ShaohaoLin Added directive so you can see.

Comment: @georgeawg Added directive declaration.

Comment: @Chrillewoodz Thank-you. That directive calls another controller `CoFormsCtrl`. I need to see the code for that.

Comment: @georgeawg That's the first snippet.

Answer (score 0):

Change this:

```
/* This is always returning undefined atm, still search for the cause */
coForms.getCurrentOption = function(select) {
    return select.currentOption; 
};
```

To this:

```
coForms.getCurrentOption = function(select) {
    return select.currentOption || coForms.default;
};
```

In your directive, you have bound the `default` attribute of the directive's HTML to the `default` property of your controllers scope.

```
coForms.directive('coSelect', [function() {

    return {
        restrict: 'E',
        scope: {
            default: '=',
            list: '=',
            label: '@'
        },
        controller: 'CoFormsCtrl',
        controllerAs: 'co',
        templateUrl: 'app/views/components/co-forms/co-select.html',
        link: function(scope, element, attrs) {

        }
    };
}]);
```

Comment: This doesn't work, the problem isn't that I'm not getting the default value, but rather that the select.currentOption value isn't there when I try to fetch it and return it.